# Vuejs x5-gmaps Map Markers Not Showing

Tags: vue.js, google-maps

I am using vue2 x5-gmaps to create a map and display the location of all properties in my db. While my map is displayed, there no markers on it despite the fact that i have specified the marker positions. If i log the latitude and longitude from the object, it is displayed correctly. Any assistance or recommendations on what i need to improve will be appreciated.

My code looks like this :

```
<div class="mapImgDiv"> 
   <gmaps-map> 
      <gmaps-marker v-for="(item, i) in propsForMap" :key="i" :position="{lat : parseFloat(item.lat) , lng: parseFloat(item.long) }" />
   </gmaps-map>
</div>
```

My method looks like this, im using firebase

```
const self = this;
        self.loading_me = true;
        db.collection("Properties")
        .where("homelocation", "==", location)
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              const data = doc.data();
              self.propsForSale.push(data);
              self.propsForMap.push(data);
            });
            this.loading_me = false;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

A snapshot of the data :

```
{
"lat" : -1.2804047,
"location: : "Kikuyu Road",
"long" : 36.695223,
"period" : "Month"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct, i added a center for the map so that i could view my ideal location better.

```
mapOptions: {
   center: { lat: -1.3031934, lng: 36.5672003 },
   zoom: 10
}
```

```
<gmaps-map :options="mapOptions"> 
              <gmaps-marker v-for="(item, i) in propsForMap" :key="i" :position="{lat: parseFloat(item.lat), lng: parseFloat(item.long)}" />
            </gmaps-map>
```